# Can sill plates extend one inch beyond the foundation wall to accommodate foam insulation?

Tags: building

Is it ok to have the sill plate 1 inch past the concrete all the way around the house to allow for 2 in foam to the foundation.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is a fairly common practice. More important is that the joists, walls, and anything else bearing on the plate have adequate support directly below from the foundation (not including the overhang).

It's also standard practice that the designer or engineer draw this into plans. Floor truss providers will need to account for the additional length needed, for example.

Comment: Would this apply only or mainly to 2 x 6 sill plates? Is it acceptable to overhang 2 x 4 sill plates by 1 inch?

Comment: It depends on many other factors. I can't answer that question in isolation. I can say that I don't recall ever seeing 2x4s used as sill plates, and typically you'd oversize your design lumber to make the extension.

Comment: @JimStewart, 2X4 can be used as a sill plate, if I remember right, the joists need 2" to bear on without the use of hangers of a sort. A 2x6 plate will allow that bearing surface with the 1" outside overhang.

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid it because the projection interrupts the drainage plane of the wall. This complicates flashing and creates a greater likelihood of bulk water intrusion. Sure, one can hope that the workers responsible for flashing get it right, but hope often isn't much of a plan and even with traditional/local practices, there's still plenty of hope.

In general, the traditional practices of construction will tend to lead to fewer unpleasant surprises.